# Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, $=\{\alpha:\alpha\in \}\subseteq M$ be an uncountable collection of disjoint sets with positive finite measure. Show that $\mu$ cannot be $\sigma$-finite.

Is the best approach to proceed by contradiction? So assume $\mu$ $\sigma$-finite. So $X$ can be written as a countable union of measurable sets with finite measure? Where would I go from there?

Answer (score 2):

First of all note that since there are uncountably many $E_\alpha$ and countably many intervals of the form $[1/(n+1),1/n)$, there must be uncountably many $E_\alpha$ with $\mu(E_\alpha)>1/m$ for some positive $m\in\Bbb N$, so assume wlog that all $E_\alpha$ have measure at least $1/m$.

Now if we write $X$ as a countable union $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$ we have again countably many $X_n$ and uncountably many $E_\alpha$, so there must be some $m$ such that $X_m$ contains infinitely many $E_\alpha$.
Now using that the $E_\alpha$ are disjoint and $\mu(E_\alpha)>1/m$ we get $\mu(X_m)=\infty$, so the measure is not $\sigma$-finite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a proof by contradiction is fine. Start by assuming that $X=\bigcup_{n\ge 0}S_n$, where each $S_n$ has finite measure. For each $\alpha\in A$ there must be an $n(\alpha)\ge 0$ such that $\mu(A_\alpha\cap S_{n(\alpha)})>0$. $A$ is uncountable, so there must be an $m\ge 0$ and an uncountable $A_0\subseteq A$ such that $n(\alpha)=m$ for each $\alpha\in A_0$. Now show that there must be a positive rational number $r$ and an uncountable $A_1\subseteq A_0$ such that $\mu(A_\alpha\cap S_m)\ge r$ for all $\alpha\in A_1$. Why is this impossible?